# laravel 5.5 - inject more data into paginate collections

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 tables:

`profiles` - for user profiles.
`posts` - for user posts.

`posts` only has a `user_id` from `profiles`, to keep the table clean.

my `HomeController` have a function that get all published posts:

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::where('publish','=',1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DSC')->paginate(5);
        return view('home',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }
```

which `post` only contains `user_id` to link it back to its owner. How can I use the `user_id` from `$posts` to retrieve user data (user_name, user_image) and append it to its specific post?

I tried:

```
foreach ($posts->items() as $p) {
 $profile = Profile::where('user_id','=',$p->user_id)->first();
 $p->put('profile',$profile);
}
```

and I get an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put()

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why you are using $p->put('profile',$profile);

Comment: i thought `put()` is to inject data. No?

Answer (score 0):

this is user model define a relationship method inside the user model

```
 class User extends Authenticatable {
   public function userPosts(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\User_post','user_id');
   }
 }
```

this is user post model

```
class User_post extends Authenticatable {
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
 }
}
```

then from your homecontroller  the existing code

```
 public function index() {
    $posts = Post::where('publish','=',1)->orderBy('created_at', 
     'DSC')->paginate(5);
     return view('home',['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

then in your view

```
<?php  foreach ($posts->items() as $p) { 
echo $p->"column name";
echo $p->users->"column name";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/is-there-any-way-to-add-attribute-to-objects-in-collection).

So my new code is:

```
foreach ($posts->items() as $p) {
 $profile = Profile::where('user_id','=',$p->user_id)->first();
 $p['profilename'] = $profile['name'];
 $p['profileicon'] = $profile['icon'];
 $p['profilebackground'] = $profile['background'];
}
```